# Combining events that are on the same day into one in Calendar using Date Repeat API

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Im using the Date Repeat API to set events that occur every week. However, date repeat only let's you set the event for one time(hour and minute). To solve this limitation I just created another repeat input in the content type. 
It works great, but I want the node titles that show in my calendar for the two time slots to be displayed as one. So, if I have three timeslots on one day it will only appear as one.

I tried intercepting the View results by making a custom module but it only came back with the node's information without any info on the actual day it will be on.

```
 [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 145
            [node_title] => Repeat 1
            [node_data_field_recurring_field_recurring_value] => 2011-05-19T20:00:00
            [node_data_field_recurring_field_recurring_rrule] => RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TH,FR;UNTIL=20110722T235959Z;WKST=SU
            [node_data_field_recurring_delta] => 0
            [node_type] => test_event
            [node_vid] => 145
            [node_data_field_specific_date_field_specific_date_value] => 2011-06-15T16:00:00
            [node_data_field_specific_date_delta] => 0
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_field_recurring_2_value] => 2011-05-19T00:00:00
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_field_recurring_2_rrule] => RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,FR;UNTIL=20110722T235959Z;WKST=SU
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_delta] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 145
            [node_title] => Repeat 1
            [node_data_field_recurring_field_recurring_value] => 2011-05-19T20:00:00
            [node_data_field_recurring_field_recurring_rrule] => RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TH,FR;UNTIL=20110722T235959Z;WKST=SU
            [node_data_field_recurring_delta] => 0
            [node_type] => test_event
            [node_vid] => 145
            [node_data_field_specific_date_field_specific_date_value] => 2011-06-15T16:00:00
            [node_data_field_specific_date_delta] => 0
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_field_recurring_2_value] => 2011-05-20T00:00:00
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_field_recurring_2_rrule] => RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,FR;UNTIL=20110722T235959Z;WKST=SU
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_delta] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 145
            [node_title] => Repeat 1
            [node_data_field_recurring_field_recurring_value] => 2011-05-19T20:00:00
            [node_data_field_recurring_field_recurring_rrule] => RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TH,FR;UNTIL=20110722T235959Z;WKST=SU
            [node_data_field_recurring_delta] => 0
            [node_type] => test_event
            [node_vid] => 145
            [node_data_field_specific_date_field_specific_date_value] => 2011-06-15T16:00:00
            [node_data_field_specific_date_delta] => 0
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_field_recurring_2_value] => 2011-05-23T00:00:00
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_field_recurring_2_rrule] => RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,FR;UNTIL=20110722T235959Z;WKST=SU
            [node_data_field_recurring_2_delta] => 2
        )
```

As you can see, it only returns the Repeat rule, so i'm thinking the Calendar module must do the calculations after. But where?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different approach entirely.  Create a node reference which creates a parent to child relationship between events.  Then in your View just exclude events that have parent nodes.

You'd have to modify your event template to display the child events.

From a data entry standpoint this would take more work per event unless some other customization to make it efficient to input was done.  Haven't used this but it seems like it could speed up multiple node creations, http://drupal.org/project/editview